# Read Remote XML file from Hardware Device in vb.net (Protocol Violation)

Tags: vb.net, http

I have a hardware device with a small web server built into it. I do not control how the web server works or is programmed. It sends back a small XML file when you request it, the problem is that the server does NOT send back any header information.

Here is the ways I have attempted to connect to it. (I have even placed the device on its own static ip for you to test - included in the code snippet below).

```
Dim request As HttpWebRequest = HttpWebRequest.Create("http://96.39.92.3:81/state.xml")
request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Get
' I Have added the following two lines to test, they do not help alone or together.
' I also added:   <httpWebRequest useUnsafeHeaderParsing="true" /> to the config file.
request.ProtocolVersion = HttpVersion.Version10
request.ServicePoint.Expect100Continue = False
Dim oResponse As HttpWebResponse = request.GetResponse()
Dim reader As New StreamReader(oResponse.GetResponseStream())
Dim tmp As String = reader.ReadToEnd()
oResponse.Close()
If oResponse.StatusCode = "200" Then
     MsgBox(tmp)
Else
     Throw New ApplicationException("Error Occurred, Code: " & oResponse.StatusCode)
End If
```

I have also tried using a XmlTextReader with the same results.

Thanks for your help.

EDIT: Fiddler Response (Used Chrome to Request Document)

```
RAW REQUEST:
GET http://96.39.92.3:81/state.xml HTTP/1.1
Host: 96.39.92.3:81
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2272.89 Safari/537.36
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8


RAW RESPONSE:
HTTP/1.0 200 This buggy server did not return headers

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<datavalues>
<relaystate>1</relaystate>
<inputstate>0</inputstate>
<rebootstate>0</rebootstate>
<totalreboots>0</totalreboots>
</datavalues>
```

With Fiddler open, the httpwebrequest above works. Fiddler must add the headers back in before it gets to the .net application.

Edit 2: Adjusted Header values for request. This makes icepickles tcpclient work for me. The cookie value was required.

```
WriteTextToStream(stream, tcpClient, "GET /state.xml?relayState=1 HTTP/1.0" & ControlChars.CrLf & _
" Accept: image/gif, image/x-xbitmap, image/jpeg, image/pjpeg, application/x-shockwave-flash, application/vnd.ms-excel, application/vnd.ms-powerpoint, application/msword, */*" & ControlChars.CrLf & _
"Referer: " & ControlChars.CrLf & "Accept -Language : en -gb" & ControlChars.CrLf & _
"Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" & ControlChars.CrLf & _
"User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.7.10) Gecko/20050716 Firefox/1.0.6" & ControlChars.CrLf & _
"Host: 192.168.1.232" & ControlChars.CrLf & _
"Connection: Keep -Alive" & ControlChars.CrLf & ControlChars.CrLf & _
"Cookie:")
```

Comment: could you make use fiddler to show the response of the request? Or check with a browser what it gets as a reply?

Comment: Just edited the question with the fiddler information.

Comment: Probably a stupid question, but 100% sure it's http and not ftp or something else?

Comment: yes, I can access the url in my browser just fine using the http://96.39.92.3:81/state.xml url. 

This is the XML returned:
    `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<datavalues>
<relaystate>1</relaystate>
<inputstate>0</inputstate>
<rebootstate>0</rebootstate>
<totalreboots>0</totalreboots>
</datavalues>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I restarted this post, based on the comments, the original reply should still be in the edit chain, in case somebody needs/wants it.

The idea is, instead of using the HttpWebRequest, that has all the extra checks build in, you just connect with your server using a TcpClient or since your extra question, try to connect with the server using the basic Socket, and request your data manually (and ignore the fact that you don't get headers, just the file in the response)

The following thing works from my computer to request the url, i'm sure it would also work with the previous TcpClient (see edit), but in this case, i just used the  System.Net.Sockets.Socket instead.

The error in the previous version was actually that i used C# \r\n instead of VB.net VbCrLf in a string literal, my mistake ;)

```
Imports System.Net.Sockets
Imports System.Net
Imports System.Text

Module Module1
    Sub WriteTextToStream(ByRef stream As NetworkStream, text As String)
        Dim buffer As Byte() = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(text)
        stream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)
    End Sub

    Function CreateHeaders(ParamArray headers() As KeyValuePair(Of String, String)) As String
        Dim message As New StringBuilder()
        If headers IsNot Nothing Then
            For Each kvp In headers
                message.AppendLine(kvp.Key & ": " & kvp.Value)
            Next
        End If
        Return message.ToString()
    End Function

    Function DownloadSocketClient(server As String, port As Integer, path As String, host As String) As String
        Dim hostEntry = Dns.GetHostEntry(server)
        Dim ipEndPoint As New IPEndPoint(hostEntry.AddressList(0), port)
        Dim textResponse As String = String.Empty

        Using tcpClient As New Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp)

            tcpClient.Connect(ipEndPoint)

            Dim networkHost As String = host & ":" & port
            Dim headerMessage As String = CreateHeaders(
                New KeyValuePair(Of String, String)("Host", networkHost)
            )

            ' autoconnect
            Using stream As NetworkStream = New NetworkStream(tcpClient)
                ' send request to server
                WriteTextToStream(stream, String.Format("GET /{1} HTTP/1.1{3}{2}{3}", networkHost, path, headerMessage, Environment.NewLine))

                'wait till data is available
                While Not stream.DataAvailable
                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1)
                End While

                ' get the response from the networkstream
                Dim requestSize As Integer = tcpClient.ReceiveBufferSize
                Dim result As Integer
                Dim readRequest(requestSize) As Byte
                While stream.DataAvailable
                    result = stream.Read(readRequest, 0, requestSize)
                    textResponse &= System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(readRequest, 0, result)
                End While
            End Using
        End Using
        Return textResponse
    End Function

    Sub Main()
        Dim fileContent As String = DownloadSocketClient("stackoverflow.server.textconnects.com", 81, "state.xml", "stackoverflow.server.textconnects.com")
        Console.WriteLine("Received file: " & vbCrLf & fileContent)
        Console.ReadLine()
    End Sub

End Module
```

Comment: I gave this a try and it works for the buggy server you wrote, but not the actual device I have. I did generate a dns entry for it, if you would be willing to see what went wrong for me: http://stackoverflow.server.textconnects.com:81/state.xml  `Dim fileContent As String = DownloadTcpClient("96.39.92.3", 81, "state.xml", "96.39.92.3")` is what I used in your app to try my server.

Comment: @Justin Yes, corrected it and it seems to be working from my end ;)

Comment: thanks for this info. I changed the header values for the request and everything fell into place. Apparently the COOKIE value is required.I am adding this to my question so if anyone ever references this they can see. Thanks again for the help.